# Creating a controller with IController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to follow an example.  It says to implement the IController interface (from System.Web.Mvc namespace).  The interface is the following :

```
public interface IController {
void Execute(RequestContext requestContext);
}
```

The project seems to use this interface (a controller file uses it) but I don't know where it goes ? If i put it in with the other controller file it doesn't work.... please advise

here is the controller that is using the interface

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ControllersAndActions.Controllers
{
    public class BasicController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Basic
        public void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            string controller = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            string action = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

            if (action.ToLower() == "redirect")
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Derived/Index");
            }

            else
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(
                    string.Format("Controller: {0}, Action: {1}",
                    controller, action));
            }

         //   requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(
         //       string.Format("Controller: {0}, Action: {1}", controller, action));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `IController` will be implemented by `ControllerBase`, `ControllerBase` will be implemented by `Controller`, and finally `Controller` will be implemented by any of our custom controllers in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: maybe it already uses it and i forgot a view or something... the interface is just listed in an example and i don't know how it fits in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample controller implementing directly the interface:

```
public class HomeController : IController
{
    public void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var response = requestContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        response.Write("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Now when you navigate to `/Home` this controller will be executed.

On the other hand the `ControllerBase` class already implements this interface for you and provides you with much more utilities. Normally you would derive directly from the `Controller` class (which inherits `ControllerBase`) so that you have things like model binding from the request, view engine support, actions, ...

Comment: when i go to basic/index i get a The resource cannot be found. but i created another controller and could go to derived/index

Comment: Normally if you directly implement the IController interface there's no concept for actions. So you would navigate to `/Home` to have this controller executed. If you inherit your class from `Controller` you can define different actions inside.

Comment: Normally you would never need to work with this interface directly. This interface is the foundation for what a Controller represents in ASP.NET MVC and unless you write some new framework on top of it, you won't need it.